# How to find out what's keeping my app in background mode?

Tags: ios

On my test device I'm sometimes seeing my app in Settings > Battery having background activity 100% of the time for hours or days even though it's apparently not doing anything. The only background mode capability I have enabled is audio, but it's not playing any audio either at those times. When I clear it from recent apps and open it again then this doesn't happen for a few days but eventually it does again.

How can I find out what's causing this? I don't know how to reproduce it and it takes a while until the background activity shows up.

[image: battery screen]